# Añadir propiedades a un objeto desde un array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, objeto

Os comento, tengo una duda de como citar añadir propiedades a un objeto mediante un array y asignándole un valor de otra variable. Os pongo un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor.

```js
let arrFruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum"];

let objFruitShop = {};

for (i = 0; i < arrFruits.lenght; i++) {
  objFruitShop.arrFruits[i] = 0; 
}

//La idea es que me quedase algo parecido a esto para luego añadir valor segun fruta

objFruitShop = {
  "Apple": 0,
  "Orange": 0,
  "Plum": 0,
}

//Por ejemplo consultar el precio diario de la manzana y asignarlo automaticamente dentro del objeto
//así despues poder citar el precio de la manzana con

alert(objFruitShop["Apple"]); //Y que me salga el precio de la manzana que tenga asignado.
```

He utilizado ese for para intentar añadir la información al objeto pero me da error, he estado buscando información pero no encuentro nada. Tampoco se si esto así es posible, necesita alguna pequeña o hay que picar bastante mas código para hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) para crear un objeto dado un array bidimensional, donde el primer elemento es la clave, y el segundo el valor.

Para hacer ese array puedes hacer un [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) sencillo, por cada valor del array devuelves un array con el valor y un cero: `arrFruits.map(fruit => [ fruit, 0 ])`.

El resultado final sería:

```js
let arrFruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum"];
let objFruitShop = Object.fromEntries(
    arrFruits.map(fruit => [ fruit, 0 ])
);

console.log(objFruitShop);
```

Corto, y a mi parecer, sencillo.

---

Por cierto, tienes dos errores en tu código, uno es que tienes `lenght` en el for, es `length`, la "t" y la "h" están alrevés.

El otro error es acceder con el punto `.` a la propiedad que quieres crear. Necesitas acceder con corchetes `[]`, puesto que si accedes con punto intenta ir a esa propiedad, y la propiedad `arrFruits[i]` no existe, y ni si quiera quieres crearla, quieres crear la propiedad con el numbre de la fruta.

El código correcto sería:

```js
let arrFruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum"];
let objFruitShop = {};

for (i = 0; i < arrFruits.length; i++) {
  objFruitShop[arrFruits[i]] = 0; 
}

console.log(objFruitShop);
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver si lo he entendido bien: en objFruitShop, los precios son de 0 ahora mismo, y lo que quieres hacer es cambiar el precio de 'x' fruta a 'y' precio, no? Dinámicamente?

Comment: Exacto. Digamos que tengo una bbdd donde actualizan cada dia el precio de la manzana y con una funcion aparte actualizar el precio de la manzana.

Comment: y no te valdría con un prompt? es decir, si solamente quieres actualizarlo, haz un botón de actualización de cada fruta, un click event, y cuando hagas clic, que salga un prompt para actualizar el precio de dicha fruta. Al ser una variable, el precio cambiará hasta la siguiente recarga de la página. A no ser que lo guardes de verdad en una bbdd

Comment: La idea es ir ampliando el negocio de la fruta y que se actualice todo automaticamente con un click. 

Digamos que el payes es moderno y tiene un ordenador donde el pone el precio de la fruta a la que la quiere vender, yo para saber cada dia el precio al que está abro mi HTML propio y al abrirlo me gustaría que ese valor se actualizase. Pero no se como hacer lo del array y el objeto.

Comment: Pero los datos de la fruta actualizada debería sacarlos pues de una bbdd de verdad, no sería un caso hipotético, y al hacerlo mediante llamadas de sql, la actualización a la web iría con la propia llamada.

Comment: Dicho de otra manera, puedo citar una variable al momento de añadir propiedades a un objeto?

Comment: Si claro! con setAttribute puedes poner el atributo value="variable X", pero el valor de dicha variable tiene que venir de algún sitio donde se guarde dicha información, recuerdalo

Comment: Para poner un atributo que dependa del valor de una variable, tienes que acceder con corchetes. Por ejemplo: `const propiedad = 'manzana'; const objeto = {}; objeto[propiedad] = 0;`, ahora el objeto contiene `{ manzana: 0 }`, tengo una respuesta por aquí con más detalles, y otra forma de hacerlo, por si te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo una solución utilizando "Json", creando un tipo de formato json. Empezamos a hacer un `Array.map()` calculando que: `if(elIndice === 0)` e iniciando nuestro Json ([ver estructura de un Json](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON#estructura_del_json)) y, luego que donde: `else if(elIndice === Array.lenght - 1)` será el final del Json y el `else` será todo lo que este por medio.

**Por alguna razón el `jsonTemplate` al inicio dice: undefined** No logre entender por que, pero esto funcionara para removerlo: `jsonTemplate.replace("undefined", "");`

```js
let arrFruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum", "Dominican Food", "Other"];
let jsonTemplate;
const arrFruitsLength = arrFruits.length;

arrFruits.map((element, n) => {
  let value = 0;
  let finalElement = element.replace(/ /g, ""); //Elimina los espacios en blanco para evitar problemas

  if (n === 0) {
    jsonTemplate += `{"${finalElement}":${value},` //Inicia Json con { (coma al final)
  } else if (n === arrFruitsLength - 1) {
    jsonTemplate += `"${finalElement}":${value}}` //Cierra Json con } (no coma al final)
  } else {
    jsonTemplate += `"${finalElement}":${value},` //otra aparte restante (del medio) (coma al final)
  }

});
const cleaning = jsonTemplate.replace("undefined", "");
const objFruitShop = JSON.parse(cleaning);

console.log(objFruitShop);
console.log("Dominican Food is: ", objFruitShop.DominicanFood);
```

Como ejemplos también implemente una función que funciona para detectar si se quiere poner un valor distinto, en esta caso `target = {Name: "Dominican Food",Price: 10.99}`

Si se quiere cambiar algún otro solo se hace una condicional; por ejemplo, si se quiere cambiar apple: `if(element === "Apple") value = 5`

Lo mismo si quieres añadir un valor diferente, como una cadena de texto seria:

```
if(element === "seller") jsonTemplate += `"${finalElement}":"Juan",`
```

Espero que te sea útil.

### Prueba el código:

```js
let arrFruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum", "Dominican Food", "Other"];
let target = {
  Name: "Dominican Food",
  Price: 10.99
} //En caso que se quiera hacer un cambio de un valor.
let jsonTemplate;
const arrFruitsLength = arrFruits.length;

arrFruits.map((element, n) => {
  let finalElement = element.replace(/ /g, ""); //Elimina los espacios en blanco para evitar problemas

  if (n === 0) {
    jsonTemplate += `{"${finalElement}":0,` //Inicia Json con { (coma al final)
  } else if (n === arrFruitsLength - 1) {
    jsonTemplate += `"${finalElement}":0}` //Cierra Json con } (no coma al final)
  } else {
    let value = 0;
    if (element === target.Name) value = target.Price; //Se comprueba si hay algun target
    jsonTemplate += `"${finalElement}":${value},` //otra aparte restante (del medio) (coma al final)
  }

});
const cleaning = jsonTemplate.replace("undefined", "");
const objFruitShop = JSON.parse(cleaning);

console.log(objFruitShop);
console.log("Dominican Food is: ", objFruitShop.DominicanFood);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas que hay en JS para añadir una nueva propiedad a un objeto es
objeto['nueva_propiedad'] = valor.

Puedes usar esto para convertir los strings del array en objetos y asociarles un valor

```
let arrFruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum"];

let objFruitShop = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arrFruits.length; i++) {
  objFruitShop[arrFruits[i]] = 0; 
}

alert(objFruitShop["Apple"])
```